# Zend Framework 1.12 Db Select - nested WHEREs using multiple values for question marks in condition

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db-select

I'm using Zend Framework 1.12.3. I need to create a query that hasnested WHEREs, such as

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE (id = 'foo' AND name = 'bar') OR (grade = 123)
```

Here's my attempt

```
$this->getDbTable()->select()
->from($this->getDbTable(), array('*')
->where('id = ? AND name = ?', $foo, $bar)
->orWhere('grade = ?', $grade);
```

However, the outcome is

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE (id = 'foo' AND name = 'foo') OR (grade = 123)
```

instead of `name = 'bar'`

Basically, I cannot use multiple `?`s assigning each `?` a different value. Do you know any solution?

Thanks

LE: using a WHERE condition such as `->where("id = $foo and name = $bar")` does work, however it doesn't prevent injection attacks like the `?` does

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, I see no way to do it, the where clause only works with a condition, but I think that adding parentheses, you can manage the AND and OR with the right priorities.

Try this:

```
this->getDbTable()->select()
    ->from($this->getDbTable(), array('*')
    ->where('(id = ?', $foo) // add '(' before condition
    ->where('name = ?)', $bar) // add ')' after condition
    ->orWhere('grade = ?', $grade);
```

Comment: This was only an example, I've got multiple nested WHEREs. I'll try it though.

Answer (score 1):

I would use named params for binding, like so:

```
    $sql = $this->getDbTable()->select()
        ->from($this->_name, array('*'))
        ->where('id = :foo AND name = :bar')
        ->orWhere('grade = ?', 'grade');
    $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll($sql, array('foo' => 'foo', 'bar' => 'bar'));
```